# How do I send a non-http hyperlink in an email message generated by Excel macros?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using Excel macros to send an email, where the content is kept in cells. I need to send a non-http link which looks like this

`elodms://` followed by an ID

I'm assuming outlook doesn't know this form of link and it doesn't present it as a clickable link when the email is sent, like it does when inserting an email address.

Is it possible to force outlook to view it as a hyperlink? And can it be done through VBA Excel macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have done emails in Excel before.

```
Email = "Hello, <br><br>" & _
                "this is something:" & _
                   "<br><br> Thank you." & _
                   "<br><br><br> <a href='elodms://12345'>CLICK HERE</a>"
    With OutMail
        .To = "you@me.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "SUBJECT"
        .HTMLBody = Email

        .send
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you, I think remaking the e-mail body in HTML was the best choice. It is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to force outlook to view it as a hyperlink?

You can use the HTMLBody property of the MailItem class. It looks like you just need to insert the hyperlink to the body. To get this working you need to find the  tag and insert anywhere before the closing tag the following string:

```
 <a href="elodms:// followed by an ID">link text goes here</a>
```

> And can it be done through VBA Excel macros?

Yes, it can be done from Excel. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0).